# Partial Derivative theory question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

So I think I have the association correct, but I am not positive on the 2nd question which could alternatively be read as: "Can you determine from the table if the change in speed or change in temperature has a greater effect on wind chill" I've calculated the changes when holding each item constant:

[image]

The boxed deltas are the average change. Not sure if this proves anything or whether I am just playing with numbers. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: You had the right idea to calculate the average change in wind chill that results from change in temperature and wind speed. Now, divide the average change in wind chill that resukts from change in speed by the total change in speed.
$$35.25/15$$

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea to calculate the average change in wind chill that results from change in temperature and wind speed. Now, divide the average change in wind chill that results from change in speed by the total change in speed.
$$35.25/15=2.35$$
Do the same with temperature. Notice, It looks like the average change in wind chill that results from change in temperature is something else, not $77.5$. I got $38.75$. So
$$38.75/40=0.96$$

So it looks like the speed has a greater effect on the wind chill. You follow why? Probably, you do already.